# Is the set $A = \{f \in X \mid \int_{0}^{1} f(t)g(t) dt = 0\}$ closed in $C[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $g\in X = C[0,1]$ be fixed. Is the set 
$A = \{f \in X \mid \int_{0}^{1} f(t)g(t) dt = 0\}$ closed in $X$?

Comment: Yes. Sup-norm metric

Answer (score 3):

Hint : prove that the linear form $\varphi \colon f \in X \mapsto \int_0^1 f(t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \in \mathbb{C}$ is continuous. Recall that [it is equivalent for $\varphi$ to be continuous and to be a bounded operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator#Equivalence_of_boundedness_and_continuity).

Comment: clever, I like it! +1

Comment: Nice way to use this powerful result. Note to OP, M in the boundedness proof is just the max of abs(g) over the domain.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n$ be a sequence in the set $A$ converging to $f$ in the sup norm. We want show $f\in A$.

Use the estimate for all $x\in [0,1]$ for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and matching $n$
$$
f_n(x)-\epsilon<f(x)<f_n(x)+\epsilon
\\
\implies
\int_0^1f_n(x)g(x)\mathrm dx-\epsilon\int_0^1g(x)\mathrm dx<
\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\mathrm dx<
\int_0^1f_n(x)g(x)\mathrm dx+\epsilon\int_0^1g(x)\mathrm dx\\
\implies-\epsilon\int_0^1g(x)\mathrm dx<\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\mathrm dx<\epsilon int_0^1g(x)\mathrm dx\\
\implies\left |\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\mathrm dx\right|<\epsilon\left|\int_0^1g(x)\mathrm dx\right|\implies 
\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\mathrm dx=0
$$
where we have used that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary and the integral of $g$ is finite. We may conclude $f\in A$ and $A$ contains its limit points. You may conclude $A$ is closed.

Comment: @Manoj certainly, good luck